# Flutter: does not enter function

Tags: android, flutter, dart

In the release version, the application does not enter the function. In debug everything is done correctly. In the code above: handler-1 is displayed, but handler-2 is not displayed.

```dart
void add(MeasuringDto measuringDto) async{
    if(!showIsOn && measuringDto.isFilled){
      count++;
      if(count % rangeToPost == 0){
        measurings.add(measuringDto);
      }
      if(measurings.length >= countToPost){
        showIsOn = true;
        print("handler-1");
        await handler(measurings);
        print("handler-2");
        measurings.clear();
        showIsOn = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

*update

I think I found the reason: I listen to the stream using the lambda function. As far as I understand, in the debug mode, this lambda is executed in a separate thread, and in release mode - in the UI thread. And since the stream very often generates new data, in the releas, the UI thread is fully loaded. But I still do not understand how to solve this problem, how to free the UI thread.

```dart
var subscription = characteristic.value.listen((value) {
  _measuringPool.add(MeasuringDto(value));
});
```

*update-2

```dart
  void _measuringHandler(List<MeasuringDto> measuringDtos) async {
    CardioDto cardioDto = new CardioDto(measuringDtos);
    try {
      await writeECG(cardioDto);
    } on DataPostFailedException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

void writeECG(CardioDto cardioDto) async {
  var response = await http.post(address + "addECGMeasurements",
      body: cardioDto.toJson(), headers: headers);
  updateCookie(response);
  var dataAnswerDto = DataAnswerDto.fromJson(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode != 200 || !dataAnswerDto.success) {
    print("Error while posting ECG measurements: " + dataAnswerDto.error);
    throw DataPostFailedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: might be the case, as you put await  before, might be handler's future is not providing the response of its execution

Comment: what does your handler do?

Comment: *update-2 question

Answer (score 0):

Please tell a little more about your handler(measurings) function.

I had the same issue, when my called function accessed the internet.
As I didn't have internet access requested in my AndroidManifes.xml it worked fine in debug mode, but threw error in release mode...